# Have floating div hug right side and accommodate scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to find a solution to this, but I dont know if maybe Im not wording it correctly because I can't seem to find an answer.

I have a page with a 'quick links' button which is designed to float against the right hand side of the screen while scrolling.

I have used the following to get the effect (the right attriubte is to hide the menu which shows when you click on the element.)

```
#quickLinks {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    right: -250px;
}
```

This is all working pretty fine, but I've found that im struggling to accomodate when a scroll bar is present or not.

So ive added a bit of 'padding' to the right attribute to stick out a little when there is a scroll bar (which my page generally has), but since there is no scroll bar visible on an ipad, for instance, there is that padded gap.

Ive noticed that using 'absolute' rather than fixed seems to get the hugging effect right, but then I lose the floating scroll.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :)

thanks!

Comment: so what's the specific problem ? you get a spacing when there is no scrollbar ? and is fine when there is ? can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Yes, so basically Im always accomodating a scroll bar. But there will be instances where there wont be a scroll bar (either on mobile, where the scroll bar is not visible, but there), or on pages where a scroll bar is not needed at all.

Hmm, Ive tried to replicate the issue in JSFiddle, but what im noticing is that Im able to 'hug' the right hand screen, and it moves with the appearance of a scroll bar.

What ive also noticed, is that my div appears 'below' the scroll bar, if i give it a negative value, while in my environment it is above.

Could it being 'above' have some effect?

Comment: Just to give more context, im adding this element to a rather large Sharepoint master page, so I might be having some trouble placing the element correctly so it is in the right content container of the scroll bar. Right now I think im in a completely different container, that I think thats why Im failing to accommodate it since its not aware of it...

Comment: I feel bad now, as I am thinking this may be a different problem completely. 
Giving an element with the 'right: 0px' attribute hugs the scoll bar in JSFiddle, but the adding the same element to my page has the element appear above and overlapping the scrollbar. Hmm... and I cant figure out why. Sorry about this.. :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you have some other conflict in your CSS causing the issue. You might want to post your CSS file to help debug. Doing a simple fiddle like this in all browsers produces the same result - the fixed div moves slightly to the left when a scroll bar is present. To see the difference, remove some of the Lorem Ipsum text.

```css
.right {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ac metus eleifend, viverra felis at, semper elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean augue sapien, efficitur at felis at, mollis
    iaculis ante. Nullam mattis risus eget ante tempor, non laoreet libero rutrum. Donec massa dui, venenatis in fringilla ut, commodo id dui. Morbi iaculis ipsum sit amet enim venenatis, ac lacinia enim sollicitudin. Integer porttitor aliquam sollicitudin.
    Aenean elementum a orci a iaculis.</p>
  <p>Quisque sit amet tortor non augue rhoncus sagittis in non felis. Etiam pulvinar enim viverra turpis pellentesque, ut sollicitudin turpis fermentum. Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis dui nec velit feugiat imperdiet. Suspendisse efficitur quam in urna porttitor,
    quis tempor ex lacinia. Quisque a mattis ante, sed dapibus risus. Nulla nec massa eu leo molestie maximus sed nec libero. Cras eget aliquet nisl, a pharetra tellus. Cras a sem id ligula aliquet mollis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis
    in faucibus. Donec volutpat, ipsum sit amet cursus laoreet, dui massa dapibus nisi, id finibus sem nisl id dui. Vestibulum aliquet lobortis enim, ut ultrices ante. Praesent faucibus pharetra sem quis mollis.</p>
  <p>Curabitur convallis sollicitudin neque nec tincidunt. Morbi tristique blandit rutrum. Nullam sed imperdiet urna, id rutrum tortor. Aenean non dolor tempor nulla egestas placerat eu vitae magna. Sed vitae feugiat tellus. Aenean ut urna posuere, lacinia
    neque ac, efficitur sem. Phasellus at tempor turpis, non ullamcorper urna. Donec in massa euismod, euismod nisi quis, sodales turpis. Suspendisse ut lacus non massa molestie rhoncus. Duis quis dui tristique, sodales sapien vel, porta nunc. Class aptent
    taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut ultrices tincidunt lacus et pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Sed placerat odio eros, eget elementum enim tempor vitae. Sed sed laoreet nulla. Nam justo augue, ornare a quam eu, placerat luctus risus. Aenean lobortis in ex sit amet pretium. Fusce iaculis lorem arcu, posuere lacinia velit laoreet sit amet. Donec
    malesuada, elit quis rutrum ullamcorper, purus libero volutpat quam, at bibendum turpis urna vel justo. Nunc aliquet lobortis ex vitae dapibus. Nullam laoreet ullamcorper enim, dapibus posuere massa pharetra at.</p>
  <p>Integer hendrerit maximus mauris consectetur lobortis. Donec magna arcu, luctus vehicula lacus in, molestie tempus metus. Donec sollicitudin, metus sed imperdiet consequat, risus mauris placerat ligula, et volutpat ex enim nec ipsum. Morbi massa risus,
    dignissim sit amet nisl ac, efficitur lobortis dolor. Duis id porta odio. Suspendisse tempus porta erat, et laoreet lectus luctus non. Etiam vel neque et ligula cursus sodales. Nunc finibus, tortor ac rhoncus venenatis, odio nisl suscipit turpis,
    ac convallis enim quam a urna. Nam condimentum risus in magna fermentum scelerisque.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ac metus eleifend, viverra felis at, semper elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean augue sapien, efficitur at felis at, mollis
    iaculis ante. Nullam mattis risus eget ante tempor, non laoreet libero rutrum. Donec massa dui, venenatis in fringilla ut, commodo id dui. Morbi iaculis ipsum sit amet enim venenatis, ac lacinia enim sollicitudin. Integer porttitor aliquam sollicitudin.
    Aenean elementum a orci a iaculis.</p>
  <p>Quisque sit amet tortor non augue rhoncus sagittis in non felis. Etiam pulvinar enim viverra turpis pellentesque, ut sollicitudin turpis fermentum. Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis dui nec velit feugiat imperdiet. Suspendisse efficitur quam in urna porttitor,
    quis tempor ex lacinia. Quisque a mattis ante, sed dapibus risus. Nulla nec massa eu leo molestie maximus sed nec libero. Cras eget aliquet nisl, a pharetra tellus. Cras a sem id ligula aliquet mollis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis
    in faucibus. Donec volutpat, ipsum sit amet cursus laoreet, dui massa dapibus nisi, id finibus sem nisl id dui. Vestibulum aliquet lobortis enim, ut ultrices ante. Praesent faucibus pharetra sem quis mollis.</p>
  <p>Curabitur convallis sollicitudin neque nec tincidunt. Morbi tristique blandit rutrum. Nullam sed imperdiet urna, id rutrum tortor. Aenean non dolor tempor nulla egestas placerat eu vitae magna. Sed vitae feugiat tellus. Aenean ut urna posuere, lacinia
    neque ac, efficitur sem. Phasellus at tempor turpis, non ullamcorper urna. Donec in massa euismod, euismod nisi quis, sodales turpis. Suspendisse ut lacus non massa molestie rhoncus. Duis quis dui tristique, sodales sapien vel, porta nunc. Class aptent
    taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut ultrices tincidunt lacus et pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Sed placerat odio eros, eget elementum enim tempor vitae. Sed sed laoreet nulla. Nam justo augue, ornare a quam eu, placerat luctus risus. Aenean lobortis in ex sit amet pretium. Fusce iaculis lorem arcu, posuere lacinia velit laoreet sit amet. Donec
    malesuada, elit quis rutrum ullamcorper, purus libero volutpat quam, at bibendum turpis urna vel justo. Nunc aliquet lobortis ex vitae dapibus. Nullam laoreet ullamcorper enim, dapibus posuere massa pharetra at.</p>
  <p>Integer hendrerit maximus mauris consectetur lobortis. Donec magna arcu, luctus vehicula lacus in, molestie tempus metus. Donec sollicitudin, metus sed imperdiet consequat, risus mauris placerat ligula, et volutpat ex enim nec ipsum. Morbi massa risus,
    dignissim sit amet nisl ac, efficitur lobortis dolor. Duis id porta odio. Suspendisse tempus porta erat, et laoreet lectus luctus non. Etiam vel neque et ligula cursus sodales. Nunc finibus, tortor ac rhoncus venenatis, odio nisl suscipit turpis,
    ac convallis enim quam a urna. Nam condimentum risus in magna fermentum scelerisque.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ac metus eleifend, viverra felis at, semper elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean augue sapien, efficitur at felis at, mollis
    iaculis ante. Nullam mattis risus eget ante tempor, non laoreet libero rutrum. Donec massa dui, venenatis in fringilla ut, commodo id dui. Morbi iaculis ipsum sit amet enim venenatis, ac lacinia enim sollicitudin. Integer porttitor aliquam sollicitudin.
    Aenean elementum a orci a iaculis.</p>
  <p>Quisque sit amet tortor non augue rhoncus sagittis in non felis. Etiam pulvinar enim viverra turpis pellentesque, ut sollicitudin turpis fermentum. Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis dui nec velit feugiat imperdiet. Suspendisse efficitur quam in urna porttitor,
    quis tempor ex lacinia. Quisque a mattis ante, sed dapibus risus. Nulla nec massa eu leo molestie maximus sed nec libero. Cras eget aliquet nisl, a pharetra tellus. Cras a sem id ligula aliquet mollis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis
    in faucibus. Donec volutpat, ipsum sit amet cursus laoreet, dui massa dapibus nisi, id finibus sem nisl id dui. Vestibulum aliquet lobortis enim, ut ultrices ante. Praesent faucibus pharetra sem quis mollis.</p>
  <p>Curabitur convallis sollicitudin neque nec tincidunt. Morbi tristique blandit rutrum. Nullam sed imperdiet urna, id rutrum tortor. Aenean non dolor tempor nulla egestas placerat eu vitae magna. Sed vitae feugiat tellus. Aenean ut urna posuere, lacinia
    neque ac, efficitur sem. Phasellus at tempor turpis, non ullamcorper urna. Donec in massa euismod, euismod nisi quis, sodales turpis. Suspendisse ut lacus non massa molestie rhoncus. Duis quis dui tristique, sodales sapien vel, porta nunc. Class aptent
    taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut ultrices tincidunt lacus et pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Sed placerat odio eros, eget elementum enim tempor vitae. Sed sed laoreet nulla. Nam justo augue, ornare a quam eu, placerat luctus risus. Aenean lobortis in ex sit amet pretium. Fusce iaculis lorem arcu, posuere lacinia velit laoreet sit amet. Donec
    malesuada, elit quis rutrum ullamcorper, purus libero volutpat quam, at bibendum turpis urna vel justo. Nunc aliquet lobortis ex vitae dapibus. Nullam laoreet ullamcorper enim, dapibus posuere massa pharetra at.</p>
  <p>Integer hendrerit maximus mauris consectetur lobortis. Donec magna arcu, luctus vehicula lacus in, molestie tempus metus. Donec sollicitudin, metus sed imperdiet consequat, risus mauris placerat ligula, et volutpat ex enim nec ipsum. Morbi massa risus,
    dignissim sit amet nisl ac, efficitur lobortis dolor. Duis id porta odio. Suspendisse tempus porta erat, et laoreet lectus luctus non. Etiam vel neque et ligula cursus sodales. Nunc finibus, tortor ac rhoncus venenatis, odio nisl suscipit turpis,
    ac convallis enim quam a urna. Nam condimentum risus in magna fermentum scelerisque.</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
  I'm floating on the right!
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uy1tgdew/1/